# How to display bar names for a horizantal barplot on screen in r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, data-visualization, bar-chart

My bar names are too long so they go off screen. Does anyone know a fix for this?
Thanks

```
 barplot(
                                horiz = TRUE,
                                height = v5,
                                names.arg = trt_name_list,
                                main = "Results",
                                col = "blue",
                                ylab = "Treatment Number",
                                xlab = "Propotion treatment is most favourable",
                                xlim = (range(0, 1)),
                                las = 2
                            )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the left margin (see `?par` for more details) and manually place `ylab` further outside.

```
data(mtcars)
df <- mtcars[1:5,]
par(mar=c(5,10,4,2) + 0.1)
barplot(
    horiz = TRUE,
    height = df$mpg,
    names.arg = rownames(df),
    main = "Results",
    col = "blue",
    xlab = "Propotion treatment is most favourable",
    las = 2
)
title(ylab="Treatment Number", line=8)
```

Please consider posting a minimal working example with the data set defined. You might use data that are available by default, like `mtcars`.